# enableling spyjs code completion in phpstorm

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, webstorm, spy

I got the spyjs tracing running in phpstorm. But I am wondering how to enable the code completion from spy-js like it is done in webstorm. See this article here: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/10/spy-js-2-0-new-level-of-javascript-tracing/

I checked for the phpstorm version, but I only got this article ragarding tracing:

http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2014/06/tracing-debugging-and-profiling-javascript-code-with-spy-js-in-phpstorm/

but it doesn't say anything about completion...

Maybe you found a solution for enabeling autocompletion with spy-js in PHPSTORM.

Comment: Process should be exactly the same: no difference as PhpStorm = WebStorm + PHP + Databases (some plugins needs to be installed manually though). So .. what is your PhpStorm version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spy-js 2.0 features (including autocompletion) are available in PhpStorm >=8.0.2. At the moment it's not released, but [EAP build is already available](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program), just install it and spy-js plugin will suggest you to update it.